# $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has cohomological dimension 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology, divisible-groups

I would like to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has cohomological dimension 1, without using the fact that it is  a free pro-p-group.

If someone can suggest me any reference (or a hint for a proof) for this it would be very helpful!

Comment: Doesn't the $p$-divisibility of $H^2(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z)$ only show that $H^2(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ injects into $H^3(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z)$? How do you conclude?

Comment: @Claudius The $p$-divisibility of $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$ implies that the map $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$ (that is the multiplication by $p$) in the long exact sequence is surjective and so I could say that $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is zero.

Comment: You are right about the surjectivity, but this does not (yet) imply $H^2(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z) = 0$, since the long exact sequence does not necessarily stop after the second cohomologies. And if it does, I am asking how it follows.

Comment: @Claudius You are absolutely right, sorry for my mistake! I edited my question, since now I really don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You could use that $H^2(\mathbb Z_p,\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z) = \varinjlim_n H^2(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$, where the transition maps are given by inflation. Then you only need to compute the $H^2(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ and the inflation maps. This is doable, but there should be more elegant ways to do it.